# ASP.NET MVC 2, .NET 4 IIS 6 and Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, deployment

I am getting a very frequented error ( as I could find from web) but none of the solutions have helped me

I am deploying ASP.NET MVC 2 Project with Target Framework as 4.0 on IIS 6 . Thanks to [Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx) I was able to configure IIS 6 to recognize URL Routes but now I am facing another issue[image]

I have made sure of the following:

- Web service extension has 4.0.30319
  enabled/ Allowed
- Have created a separate Application
  pool for  this website
- My website has been configured with 
  correct ASP.NET Version  4.0.30319
- .aspx is mapped to right verion  :
  c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll
- Version Information: Microsoft .NET
  Framework Version:2.0.50727.3053;
  ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3053

What I think is interesting is that (ans as you can see in the screenshot)  the page seems to indicate that the website is using 
**Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3053; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3053**

Please help me get around this issue.

Thank you,

Mar

Comment: Application Pool the website is using needs to be set to .NET 4.0

Comment: Baddie- Can you advise on how to  Set Application Pool to use .NET 4.0 in IIS 6.0. . It could be a IIS 7 feature

Comment: This issue may be resolved by 4.0.3.  [You can check out the KB article here.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2599651)  @ me and let me know if this fixes your issue, I may try to get a canonical question/answer for this error and close dupes.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I know that on iis7 to get it work need specify .net framework version for app pool. Mb here also need to change version of framework from 2 to 4.

Comment: in IIS 6.0 under Application Pool I did not find any place to specify which version of framework to use.

Comment: I also don't know where it place. But I found some articles, mb it help you: http://www.aspnethostingnews.com/index.php/archives/87 http://johan.driessen.se/archive/2010/04/13/getting-an-asp.net-4-application-to-work-on-iis6.aspx

Answer (score 1):

All,

I am answeing my own question -
 on IIS 7 changing the application pool works but on IIS 6 I couldnot make  code compiled in framework 4 work.

I downgraded my application framework to 3.5 ( ASP.NET  on 2.0.50727). I tried for two days all workarounds and then decided to take this path to save time.

On my Application Server , I unregistered (ASPNET-REGIIS with option -u)
asp.net framework 4.0.30319 and registered  on 2.0.50727 (ASPNET-REGIIS with option -r)

This decision was also taken on the fact that our IT Dept dont have any plans to upgrade servers to 2008 and IIS 7 in near future.

Regards,

Mar